# Magento 2.2.4 - Back Button in Admin Always Displays as "Back to register or connect an account"

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, magento2.2.4

After updating to **Magento 2.2.4** I have noticed that the admin area "Back" button now reads "Back to register or connect an account" wherever you are within the backend.

From what I can tell is seems to be coming from translations within the new **Amazon pay and login module**:

```
amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module/src/Core/i18n/en_US.csv:"Back","Back to register or connect an account"
```

So feel I may just need to remove this line here or apply differently as this is applying to every **back** instance in my admin area.

Is there a way to just overide this translation and apply to the admin area without modifying the core code (or a better solution)?

Normally the structure from within vendor is like so:

```
Vendor/module-module-name
```

From there I can overide for example in my admin theme like so:

```
Vendor_ModuleName/il8n/en_US.csv
```

This module however has `src/Core` within the path and is also missing the `module-` at the beginning of the module folder so am unsure the correct way to override and was hoping someone could enlighten me?

e.g.

```
app/design/adminhtml/ThemeVendor/CustomAdminTheme/Amzn_AmazonPayAndLoginMagento2Module/src/Core/i18n/en_GB.csv
```

Comment: It's everyone, not just you [#14978](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14978).

Comment: To add on to this, if you include your module en_US.csv, you can override it ***as long as*** you do **not** translate it to "Back".  If you translate it to "Go Back" or "Previous" it works; however, "Back" will doubly translate to the amazon version.

Comment: The `src/Core` and `src/Login` are separate modules, just deployed as a single composer module.  They have their own `registration.php` files.  If you want to override it in the theme, I believe you can use `Amazon_Core/i18n/en_US.csv` as the file path.  This is still a core bug though.